# Microsoft SQLEXPRESS

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, sqlsrv

This may not be real concept, but I have a small problem.

I am REQUIRED to use a software that lacks a lot of features it should have, and that I need.
That Software has propriety features that I can only use it for.

The features that I want to add I know how to do, and will have little to no problems developing them.

So the problem.
Codigniter maybe even PHP in general provides the ability to connect to MSSQL databases though a driver, 'sqlsrv' this driver does not like '.' in the database name (ex. "my.data.base.2")

The software creates this database this way. I have tried finding configs for the server, client, and everything else to just let me change the database name to not include Periods in the name. Not going to happen. I believe it is hard coded in to the software itself.

So my solution is to figure out if I can create a database with two names that share the same data set.

OR

Find out how to fix the php driver to allow '.' in the name.

any solutions?

Comment: Do [square brackets] help?

Comment: How so? adding [] to what?

Comment: Wrap the database name like this [my.data.base.2]. this is why it is not a good idea to include reserved words or punctuation in object or database names.

Comment: Square brackets did not help, yeah I wouldn't have done this. It is the required software that does this.

Comment: Can you experiment by changing the database name in SQL.  Get the connection working first, then add one DOT (.) at a time to the database name, and try again.  At least then you will know it works without the dots

Comment: Already did this, that how I know it is the '.' doing this.

Comment: Create database with the name without '.' DOTs. Connect to that database via you app. Create objects in that database that reference your table(s) within DOT database "my.data.base.2".

Comment: You could try all sorts of brackets () {} [] or even quotes ' ' or " " to see if that helps.  As you said - the driver is the issue

Comment: Cannot seem to pull in the "my.data.base.2" tables into my apps database relationship structure.

Comment: Just tried to php escape the chars of '.' by \p{2E} didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with the way the php mssql libraries parse the connection string.

I ended up converting this application to a java program.

Works Great now.